# Numpy.matmul sees array as integer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have been trying to create a class for matrixes and this is what i have already:

```
import numpy as np
import random

class matrix(): 
    def __init__(self, rows, cols): 

        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.matrix = np.array([[0 for x in range(self.cols)] for y in range(self.rows)])


    def multiply(self, a): 
        self.matrix = np.matmul(self.matrix, a)

    def randomize(self): 
        for j in range(self.rows): 
            for i in range(self.cols):

                self.matrix[j][i] = random.randint(1,10)





m = matrix(4,3)
a = matrix(3, 3)
m.randomize()
a.randomize()

m.multiply(a)
```

What i expect this to do is to multiply m with a, in a sort of matrix fashion. i have a function which gives each value a nr between 0 and 10.

But i get this error message:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

Im sure its just something small i am overlooking but if not and its a bigger issue, please dont hesitate to ask questions. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you define your `randomize()` matrix?

Comment: i exluded it so its more readable, i will add it now :)

Comment: FYI, you can initialize the matrix with `self.matrix = np.zero((rows, cols))`

Comment: Thanks didnt new about that function :)

Comment: Are you doing this for learning purposes?

Comment: Im building a simple Neural Network library, with the help of coding trains videos on youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to multiply a Numpy object, with an object of type of your matrix. In your multiply function, you should call `np.matmul(self.matrix, a.matrix)`. Also, as Barmar suggested, you can increase the performance of your code by using `self.matrix = np.zero((rows, cols))`.

```py
import numpy as np
import random

class matrix(): 
    def __init__(self, rows, cols): 

        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.matrix = np.zero((rows, cols))


    def multiply(self, a): 
        self.matrix = np.matmul(self.matrix, a.matrix)
```

Comment: Well, thats embarassing. Thanks a lot, espacially about the np.zero part. I didnt new about it. :)